# Acegi Active Directory Authentication

Tags: spring-security, directory, ldap

I am migrating a Spring-WS (Spring Webservices) application that uses Acegi security from eDirectory to Active Directory based authentication. The application uses acegi-security-1.0.3.jar.

The current LDAP configuration used for eDirectory authentication is:

ldap.locations=ldap://test_edir_server:389/o=XYZ
ldap.userDnPatterns=cn={0},ou=test,ou=Internal

The new LDAP configuration used for Active Directory authentication is:

ldap.locations=ldap://test_ad_server:389/dc=XYZ
ldap.userDnPatterns=cn={0},ou=ABC,ou=Internal,ou=DEF,dc=test,dc=xyz

When tested using the above new LDAP configuration, I am getting the below error.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Using Apache Directory Studio, I can connect to the Active Directory Studio using the above new LDAP configuration.

Any pointers where I am getting it wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace? can you connect using a simple ldapsearch to your AD?